# Add a line break in Woocommerce Product Attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Purfume product with these attributes:

```
Mint Apple Orange Lavander
```

And in the product page, inside the additional informations tab, they are displayed on the same line, separated by a comma.

```
Mint, Apple, Orange, Lavander
```

I know it's possible to do a character replacement so that a "," in the backend becomes a line break `<br/>`. But I don't know how.

I want it to look like this

```
Mint
Apple
Orange
Lavander
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_attribute` filter to change the commas into line breaks.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute', 'woocommerce_product_attributes_add_line_break', 10, 3 );
function woocommerce_product_attributes_add_line_break( $attribute_list, $attribute, $values ) {
    if ( !is_product() ) return; //Only on product page
    $attribute_list = wpautop( wptexturize( implode( '<br>', $values ) ) );
    return $attribute_list;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to make it more "safe" by replacing only the comma added by woocommerce? If for some reason I have a descriptive attribute with a comma inside, It could mess up the layout.

Comment: If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted (and possibly vote it up).